# PHPExcel how to apply text alignment horizontal fill - PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_Fill

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm using PHPExcel to create an excel doc... trying to set the cells  text alignment horizontal to fill

```
$this->objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()
    ->getAlignment()
    ->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_Fill);
```

tried to add to Alignment.php the option but that didn't work

```
const HORIZONTAL_Fill = 'fill';
```

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the constant you're looking for is

```
PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_JUSTIFY
```

all the constants that are available for PHPExcel_Style_Alignment can be found defined at the top of the PHPExcel/Style/Alignment.php file

Comment: HORIZONTAL_JUSTIFY will break the cell into multiple lines i need it to stay in one line and a set width - it should cut off what that don't fit, excel has an option fill

Comment: i'm using Microsoft excel 2008 (on mac), format -> cells -> alignment in text-alignment horizontal one of the options are fill

Comment: Will look in specs to see how its implemented; but currently it isn't supported

Comment: Added HORZONTAL_FILL option to horizontal alignment for Excel5/Excel2007, and HORIZONTAL_DISTRIBUTED and VERTICAL_DISTRIBUTED options for Excel2007 to latest develop branch on [github](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel)

Answer (score 7):

***Valid Alignment Styles***

**Horizontal alignment styles** Can you use :  `HORIZONTAL_LEFT = 'left', HORIZONTAL_RIGHT = 'right', HORIZONTAL_CENTER  = 'center', HORIZONTAL_CENTER_CONTINUOUS = 'centerContinuous' and HORIZONTAL_JUSTIFY  = 'justify'.`

**Vertical alignment styles**   Can you use : `VERTICAL_BOTTOM = 'bottom', VERTICAL_TOP = 'top', VERTICAL_CENTER = 'center', VERTICAL_JUSTIFY = 'justify' and HORIZONTAL_GENERAL = 'general'.`

Answer (score 1):

For the PHPOffice newer version (Laravel 5.* Syntax)

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment;
$style = array(
            'alignment' => array(
                'horizontal' => Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,
            )
        );
$activeSheet->getStyle("A1:D1")->applyFromArray($style);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me.

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A11')->getAlignment()->applyFromArray(
     array('horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_FILL)
    );
```